# How to fix Delayed Job deserialization errors after upgrading from Rails 4.2 to 5.1+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am working on upgrading an app from Rails 4.2 to 5.2.  I have am running into an issue were jobs that were created in 4.2 are raising errors when they are invoked under Rails 5.2.

`Delayed::DeserializationError (Job failed to load: not delegated...`

I have narrowed it down to a problem after moving from 5.0 to 5.1.  In 5.0.7 there is no problem but there is in 5.1.0.  I can reproduce on a simple test case (taken from job.handler) by doing `YAML.load(yml)` where yml:

```
object: !ruby/object:Account
  raw_attributes:
    id: '8469'
  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet
    attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash
      types:
        id: &4 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Integer
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 8
          range: !ruby/range
            begin: -9223372036854775808
            end: 9223372036854775808
            excl: true
      values:
        id: '8469'
        created_at: '2019-11-15 21:16:15.257401'
      additional_types: {}
      materialized: true
      delegate_hash:
        id: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
          name: id
          value_before_type_cast: '8469'
          type: *4
          value: 8469
        created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
          name: created_at
          value_before_type_cast: '2019-11-15 21:16:15.257401'
          type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
            subtype: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::DateTime
              precision: 
              scale: 
              limit: 
          value: 2019-11-15 21:16:15.257401000 Z
  new_record: false
  active_record_yaml_version: 0
```

That gives the error `ArgumentError (not delegated)`.  I have found that removing the `subtype` under created_at makes the problem go away but not idea why.  I have tried changing the subtype to something simple like an integer and get the same problem.

Anyone have thoughts on how to approach this?  I am really surprised that I have not found any info on others running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was bigger than just 5.0 being able to serialize but 5.1 couldn't.  There are a bunch of methods and classes that have been moved or removed in Rails 5 so it is just difficult to deserialize.  With some help by posting an issue in the delayed job issues (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/1111) I was able to come up with a solution.  I ended up writing the following migration that deserializes and then serializes all delayed_jobs.

**migrate_dj_to_rails5.rb**

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

class MigrateDjToRails5 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  include MigrationHelper

  def up
    execute create_backup('delayed_jobs')
    migrator = DelayedJobMigrator.new(Delayed::Job.all)
    migrator.migrate
  end

  def down
    execute copy_field_from_backup('delayed_jobs', 'handler')
    execute load_dropped_records_from_backup('delayed_jobs')
  end

  class DelayedJobMigrator
    def initialize(jobs = Delayed::Job.all)
      @exceptions = []
      @corrected_job_ids = []
      @deleted_job_ids = []
      @jobs = jobs
      @progress_bar = ProgressBar.create(total: jobs.count, format: "%t: |%w| %e")
    end

    def migrate_job(job)
      begin
        data = YAML.load_dj(job.handler)
      rescue
        begin
          job.payload_object = TempToRuby.create.accept(Psych.parse(job.handler))
        rescue => exception
          if exception.message =~ /Couldn't find (.+) with 'id'=/
            # job is no longer valid
            @deleted_job_ids << job.id
            job.delete
          end       
          @exceptions << exception
          return
        end
        job.save
        @corrected_job_ids << job.id
      end
    end

    def migrate
      @jobs.find_each do |job|
        migrate_job(job)
        @progress_bar.increment
      end

      @corrected_job_ids.each do |id|
        puts "Corrected job_id: #{id}"
      end

      @exceptions.each do |exception|
        puts "Exceptions:: #{exception}"
      end

      puts "#{@corrected_job_ids.count} jobs corrected"
      puts "#{@exceptions.count} exceptions encountered (should be same as jobs deleted)"
      puts "#{@deleted_job_ids.count} jobs deleted"
    end

    class TempToRuby < Delayed::PsychExt::ToRuby
      def visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping(object)
        if %r{^!ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet}.match(object.tag.to_s)
          {}
        elsif %r{^!ruby/object:(.+)$}.match(object.tag.to_s)
          klass = resolve_class(Regexp.last_match[1])
          if klass < ActiveRecord::Base
            payload = Hash[*object.children.map { |c| accept c }]
            return super unless payload['raw_attributes']
            id = payload['raw_attributes'][klass.primary_key]
            klass.unscoped.find(id)
          else
            super
          end
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**migration_helper.rb**

```
# Helper module for commonly used migration related methods
module MigrationHelper
  def create_backup(table_name, suffix='_copy')
    table_name_copy = table_name + suffix

    <<-SQL
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #{table_name_copy};
      CREATE TABLE #{table_name_copy} AS TABLE #{table_name};
    SQL
  end

  def copy_field_from_backup(table_name, field, suffix='_copy')
    table_name_copy = table_name + suffix
    records_to_update = <<-SQL
      UPDATE #{table_name}
      SET #{field} = #{table_name_copy}.#{field}
      FROM #{table_name_copy}
      WHERE #{table_name_copy}.id = #{table_name}.id
    SQL
  end

  def load_dropped_records_from_backup(table_name, suffix='_copy')
    table_name_copy = table_name + suffix

    <<-SQL
      INSERT INTO #{table_name}
      SELECT #{table_name_copy}.* FROM #{table_name_copy} 
      LEFT JOIN #{table_name} on #{table_name}.id = #{table_name_copy}.id
      where #{table_name}.id is null
    SQL
  end
end
```